# Are there any reliable metrics which indicate that Clojure or Node.js a better tool for building a web api?

Tags: node.js, clojure

Where may I find concrete evidence, if it exists, that Clojure or Node.js have an advantage over the other in web api that is overwhelmingly used for I/O processes (very few computational processes)?

This debate is "raging" in my office.  We maintain a large "salesforce" type of web/mobile app build on MySQL -> Clojure -> Angular 7/Ionic.

Comment: This asks for *concrete evidence*. Surely an appeal for facts ought not to be suppressed.

Comment: Maybe you can start by looking at https://github.com/ptaoussanis/clojure-web-server-benchmarks and https://github.com/abtv/web-benchmarks ... the latter includes simple web servers in Clojure, Go and Rust, probably you can extend it to include a NodeJS based one and get metrics for your workload and hardware.

Comment: You may be interested in this thread on the Clojure mailing list re Clojure/Go:  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/pedestal-users/ybZK_Enf83Y/discussion    You could also re-post your question there.

Comment: The question as stated is very broad.  Is a specific facet you are interested in (e.g., performance, overall cost, time to market, etc.)?  The more specific you can be, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is largely I/O bound, the distinction will likely not matter from a performance perspective - both languages have prior examples of performant I/O heavy services. You are likely going to save more developer time using a slightly worse tool you are more comfortable with than using a cutting-edge, blazing fast language no one has experience with.

Comment: Indeed, if your backend is just passing data MySQL <--> client then it doesn't matter much *what* you use.